# Hyper-V Virtual Desktop Infrastructure

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services, remote-desktop-gateway

We're designing a virtual desktop infrastructure (VDI) on Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 Remote Desktop Services using Windows 7 clients and I need some information on how it works in order to see if how we have it on paper is going to work.

We need the virtual machines on the VDI to be within the DMZ IP range and use the Meraki as their default gateway. The VDI hosts need to be on the internal network IP range, and the DMZ Windows 7 machines need to be separated from the local LAN.

On paper, we have a Meraki firewall off the back of our perimeter firewall in a DMZ. The virtual servers are on the core switch internal LAN. The Switch is both VLAN 1 and 3, and the Meraki is VLAN 3 only and the Windows 7 machines are on the same IP range as the Meraki.

The question I have is, can the VDI host machines that are not on the local domain? Will any port forwarding need to be done to get RDP to work to the Windows 7 VMs? I can see this working fine if the RDP traffic goes to the Hyper-V server itself on the local LAN IP range and the server returns the video feed for the VM. Problems will occur if the RDP connection is to the Windows 7 machine itself on the DMZ IP scheme as there will be no route to that IP range and I don't want to add a route.

Can anyone enlighten me as to which machine the RDP will be established?

Edit: Just to clarify, the Windows 7 Machines will not be on the domain.

Comment: Why would you use Windows 7 in 2017?

Comment: I appreciate your concern but the company hasn't moved to Win 10 yet. Not my decision, that's just the way it is.

Comment: Have you considered 8.1 maybe? 7's almost dangerous these days